# SQL Trigger Using Variables

Tags: sql, triggers

I need help creating this trigger, any help will be appreciate it, I can't save this script, it's saying 'Invalid column name OfferId'. But I checked all the columns names and they are correct

```
  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.OrderOffer_UpdatedUnits
  ON dbo.OrderOffer
  FOR  UPDATE
  AS

  BEGIN
  DECLARE @OfferId char(5)     SET  @OfferId = (Select OfferId From INSERTED i, OrderOffer a Where   i.OrderOfferid = a.OrderOfferid);
  DECLARE @UnitsAvailable int  SET  @UnitsAvailable = (Select SUM(UnitsAvailable) From dbo.Offer    Where OfferId=@OfferId);


  UPDATE dbo.OrderOffer SET dbo.UnitsAvailable = @UnitsAvailable
  FROM INSERTED i, OrderOffer a
  WHERE i.OrderOfferid = a.OrderOfferid 

 END
```

Comment: Remember, an update may affect multiple rows; not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.OrderOffer_UpdatedUnits
ON dbo.OrderOffer
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE a
    SET dbo.UnitsAvailable = 
        (
            Select SUM(b.UnitsAvailable) 
            From dbo.Offer b 
            Where b.OfferId = a.OfferId
        )
    FROM OrderOffer a
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i
    ON i.OrderOfferid = a.OrderOfferid

END
```

NB: I removed the variables since that would assume you only updated one row at a time.  Even if the update runs over multiple rows, the above should still work.

Comment: Thank you John, I am getting this error: Incorrect syntax near ')' in line 8

Comment: No worries / apologies; I'd left some of the original code in there, having stripped other bits out.  Should be OK now.

Comment: JohnLBevan, when you have time could you please help me with my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey @Carlos, please could you give me a bit more info on what more you need help with?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: JohnLBevan,Good to hear from you again, last week i was struggling to write a trigger, I opened a new question here is the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005683/sql-trigger-that-updates-two-tables?noredirect=1#comment42586618_27005683] It took me a while to make this trigger work, but the code looks messy, I was hoping if you can help me to simplify it. I will really appreciate it. have a good day!