# SQL Trigger that updates two tables

Tags: sql, triggers, azure-sql-database

I am new in SQL, can anybody please help me to fix the trigger bellow.

I have these 2 tables(Review and Offer), I would like to update Review table ON Insert, Update and Delete getting the data from the Offer Table. And if this is successfully updated i would like to update Offer Table with the ReviewId and ReviewDate.

I am using the SQL server provided by Azure.

UserKey and Asin are unique values so that's what I am using to link these tables.
I will realy appreciate any help!

`Review` table:

```
 ReviewId | OfferId  |  Review  |  CustomerId  |  UserKey   |   Asin    |  ReviewDate
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  25224      null        blah         null        12354ddd     123456     11/24/2014
```

`Offer` table:

```
 OfferId |  CustomerId  |  UserKey  |   Asin   |  ReviewId   |   ReviewDate |  Status
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  25224       55555        12354ddd    12345        null           null        Pending Review
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 // this trigger works, is there any other way to simplify this?
 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InserUpdateReview
 ON dbo.Review
 FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
 AS

 IF( Select Review.OfferId from Review, Inserted Where Review.ReviewId = Inserted.ReviewId ) IS NULL

 BEGIN

 //Update Review table first, this update it is working

   UPDATE a
   SET a.OfferId =  ( Select Top(1) b.OfferId  From dbo.Offer b   Where b.UserKey = a.UserKey   AND  b.ASIN= a.ASiN AND b.ReviewId IS NULL ), 
    a.CustomerId   =  ( Select Top(1) b.CustomerId    From dbo.Offer b   Where b.UserKey = a.UserKey   AND  b.ASIN= a.ASiN AND b.ReviewId IS NULL )

FROM dbo.Review a
INNER JOIN Inserted i
ON a.ReviewId=i.ReviewId AND a.OfferId IS NULL AND a.CustomerId IS NULL 


   //update Offer table here,

  UPDATE Top(1) o
  SET o.ReviewId     =  (Select r.ReviewId  From dbo.Review r   Where r.UserKey = o.UserKey  AND  r.ASIN= o.ASiN AND  r.ReviewId = ins.ReviewId  ),
    o.ReviewDate   =  getDate()
 FROM dbo.Offer o
 INNER JOIN Inserted ins
 ON o.UserKey = ins.UserKey AND o.ASIN = ins.ASIN AND o.ReviewId IS NULL

 END
```

Comment: Also: you don't mention anything about `DELETE` in your question, yet the trigger also seems to be `FOR DELETE`. At the same time, you're never looking at the `Deleted` pseudo table --> this trigger will not do anything for a `DELETE` operation....

Comment: Hello Marc_s, thank you for your response. I am using the SQL provided by Azure. As you mentioned i haven't done anything for Delete yet(I dont know how). In addition, dou you think I can create an Update to the other thable in the same trigger? Thank you in advance!

Comment: marc_c, i just updated the trigger, so far it is working as it supposed to. But the code looks a bit messy to me(based on little experience), could you please tell me if this the right way to write the script. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks messy because you need to do all sorts of `IF` and stuff to know whether you're inside an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` trigger. I would personally create **three separate triggers**, one for each operations - then it's clear from the beginning *what* this trigger deals with and you can forget a lot of those `IF` and so on statements - the code will look a lot cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below; hopefully it does what you're after; the logic's not exactly the same, but I've tried to guess what you're aiming for and code that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InserUpdateReview
ON dbo.Review
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    --if it's an update
    if exists (select top 1 1 from inserted i inner join deleted d on d.ReviewId = i.ReviewId)
    begin

        --update the review table
        UPDATE a
        SET a.OfferId = max(b.OfferId)
        , a.CustomerId = max(b.CustomerId)
        FROM dbo.Review a
        INNER JOIN Inserted i
            ON a.ReviewId = i.ReviewId 
            AND a.OfferId IS NULL 
            AND a.CustomerId IS NULL 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Offer b
            ON b.UserKey = a.UserKey   
            AND b.ASIN = a.ASiN 
            AND b.ReviewId IS NULL 

        --and the corresponding orders table
        UPDATE o
        SET o.ReviewId = max(r.ReviewId)
        , o.ReviewDate = getDate()
        FROM dbo.Offer o
        INNER JOIN Inserted ins
            ON o.UserKey = ins.UserKey 
            AND o.ASIN = ins.ASIN 
            AND o.ReviewId IS NULL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Review r
            ON r.UserKey = o.UserKey  
            AND r.ASIN = o.ASiN 
            AND r.ReviewId = ins.ReviewId

    end

END
```

NB: If you can explain your aim with this logic we may be better able to advise.

Comment: JohnLBevan, thank you so much for taking the time to write this script, you are awesome man! I will test it sometime today and I will let you know the outcome.